# From a list of strings to a dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

Say I have a list holding the following items:

```
["FOO x 2", "BAR x 11", "PERC"]
```

I would like to convert this list to a dictionary with the following result:

```
{"FOO": 2, "BAR": 11, "PERC": 1}
```

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: why does `PERC` have the value `1`?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard It's *assumed* to be "x 1" if there isn't a multiplier next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with supplying a comprehension to `dict`:

```
l = ["FOO x 2", "BAR x 11", "PERC"]
d = dict((tuple(map(str.strip, i.split('x'))) if 'x' in i else (i, 1) for i in l))
print(d)
{'BAR': '11', 'FOO': '2', 'PERC': 1}
```

Though a `for-loop` definitely beats it in readability:

```
d = {}
for i in l:
    if 'x' in i:
        k, v = map(str.strip, i.split('x'))
        d[k] = v
    else:
        d[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner:

```
d = {x[0].strip(): int(x[1]) for x in ((elm + 'x 1').split('x') for elm in lst)}

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'BAR': 11, 'FOO': 2, 'PERC': 1}
```

Alternatively, you can take advantage of the new unpacking feature with `*` in Python 3:

```
lst =  ["FOO x 2", "BAR x 11", "PERC"]

res = {}
for x in lst:
    name, *count = (x + 'x 1').split('x')
    res[name.strip()] = int(count[0])

print(res)
```

Output:
    {'BAR': 11, 'FOO': 2, 'PERC': 1}

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet code can do what you want to do

```
lst = ["FOO x 2", "BAR x 11", "PERC"];
lst1 = list()
for elem in lst:
    splited = elem.split('x')
    k = 0
    for stri in splited:
        k = k + 1
        if k == 1:
            v = stri
            u = 1
        else:
            u = stri
    ar = list()
    ar.append(v)
    ar.append(u)
    lst1.append(ar)
dic = dict(lst1)
print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more contrib to the zoo: now with list comprehension, splitting, and `if` expression:

```
pass1 = [x.split(' x ') for x in l]
# [['FOO', '2'], ['BAR', '11'], ['PERC']]
dict((t[0], int(t[1]) if len(t) > 1 else 1) for t in pass1)
# {'PERC': 1, 'BAR': 11, 'FOO': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options to choose from

```
data = ["FOO x 2", "BAR x 11", "PERC"]
```

---

```
res = { key : int(value) if value else 1
        for key, sep, value in map(lambda s: s.partition(' x '), data) }
```

---

```
res = {}
for item in data:
    key, sep, value = item.partition(' x ')
    res[key] = int(value) if value else 1
```

---

```
res = {}
for item in data:
    key, *value = item.split(' x ')
    res[key] = int(value[0]) if value else 1
```

---

```
res = {}
for item in data:
    key, value = (item.split(' x ') + [1])[:2]
    res[key] = int(value)

# Output - res
{'FOO': 2, 'BAR': 11, 'PERC': 1}
```

Note that this is assuming that your data will always be in that format, otherwise may need to include `.strip()` or other minor changes.